# how can I alter the return of a search_api based View?

Tags: views, search

I was hoping to alter the return of a search_api based View (coming from a solr index), so I implemented hook_views_pre_render. Though I can make some customization using a specific hook to alter the result returned by solr, that is not enough . But the $view->results array only contains the entity ID and search_api information (relevance score, fulltext snippet). All view data is supposed to be loaded by this phase. How can I alter certain field value in the view before it rendered to the end user?

Comment: _"All view data is supposed to be loaded by this phase."_ can you clarify what you mean by that? By definition, views will only load data for the fields you've asked it to so it's difficult to know what you might mean

Comment: yes, I agree with you, I mean all view data needed for rendering the view is supposed to be loaded by this phase. But I check the $view->results in hook_views_pre_render, I just see it only contains the entity ID and search_api information (relevance score, fulltext snippet), no other fields.

Comment: I think that's expected behaviour - I've just checked a few installations with search api on and they all do the same thing. I imagine the idea is to avoid having to go into the database

Comment: so, for a search_api based View, how can I modify the field being rendered with just knowing entity ID and relevance score, etc.?